# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Pro Globals Select

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

On a WordPress website I have three banners above the footer that sometimes repeat on other pages but the majority are different on each page overall there's around 8 different banners in total.

I have placed these into partials, and calling the partials within the page template. The content of the banners is going through Advanced Custom Fields and calling each field (Title, content, image) into the partial.

Is there a better way to do this? At the moment I am having to fill out the information on each page for the repeated banners. But the clients would like the banners to be editable, but the content wouldn't change on banners already created. I appreciate any help or better ways at doing this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Options page to do this.

Check out: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Comment: Thanks that helped!